# Automated tools to test Struts OGNL security vulnerabilities

Tags: web-application, web-scanners

I'm looking for a way to find Struts2 OGNL vulnerabilities (specifically http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-4316/

and

http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-2251/.  )

I know that attackers have such tools, and there is a Metasploit module for use when you already know the exact location of the flaw. What is a good method for finding web application pages vulnerable to these attacks (from a black box perspective)?  Also, are there tell-tale signs in the source code that an application might be vulnerable?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the use of known bad dependencies with [OWASP Dependency-Check](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check)

I found this also looking for tools which attempt to exploit the known issues repetitively.  It's looking like I may have to modify existing active vulnerability scanners.